# How to check if a specific key is present in a hash or not?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, associative-array

I want to check whether the "user" key is present or not in the session hash. How can I do this?

Note that I don't want to check whether the key's value is nil or not. I just want to check whether the "user" *key* is present.

Answer (score 1135, accepted):

`Hash`'s `key?` method tells you whether a given key is present or not.

```
session.key?("user")
```

Comment: nice: "string" accessor works for JSON.parse parsed objects, too :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the :user method worked instead

Comment: if(session["user"]) also work, but not sure about the efficiency

Answer (score 343):

While `Hash#has_key?` gets the job done, as Matz notes [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512014514/http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/43765), it has been deprecated in favour of `Hash#key?`.

```
hash.key?(some_key)
```

Comment: Nice reference to that change request and subsequent response from Matz.

Comment: Does anybody know for sure?

Comment: `#has_key` is actually not deprecated: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues/3224#issuecomment-226175176

Answer (score 56):

Hash instance has a [`key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F) method:

```
{a: 1}.key?(:a)
=> true
```

Be sure to use the symbol key or a string key depending on what you have in your hash:

```
{'a' => 2}.key?(:a)
=> false
```

Comment: Apprently existed as early as Ruby 1.6: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_hash.html#Hash.key_qm (perhaps earlier, dunno where to check documented)

Answer (score 37):

It is very late but preferably symbols should be used as key:

```
my_hash = {}
my_hash[:my_key] = 'value'

my_hash.has_key?("my_key")
 => false 
my_hash.has_key?("my_key".to_sym)
 => true 

my_hash2 = {}
my_hash2['my_key'] = 'value'

my_hash2.has_key?("my_key")
 => true 
my_hash2.has_key?("my_key".to_sym)
 => false
```

But when creating hash if you pass string as key then it will search for the string in keys.

But when creating hash you pass symbol as key then has_key? will search the keys by using symbol.

---

If you are using Rails, you can use `Hash#with_indifferent_access` to avoid this; both `hash[:my_key]` and `hash["my_key"]` will point to the same record

Comment: If you are using Rails, you can use `Hash#with_indifferent_access` to avoid this; both `:my_key` and `"my_key"` will point to the same record

Comment: This is the best answer especially when you are looking for a key coming from a variable, e.g., `my_hash.has_key? my_key.to_sym` :)

Answer (score 9):

Another way is here

```
hash = {one: 1, two: 2}

hash.member?(:one)
#=> true

hash.member?(:five)
#=> false
```

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `Hash#key?` to check if the key is present in a hash or not.

If not it will return you `false`

```
hash =  { one: 1, two:2 }

hash.key?(:one)
#=> true

hash.key?(:four)
#=> false
```

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 5, the **has_key?** method checks if key exists in hash. The syntax to use it is:

```
YourHash.has_key? :yourkey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {}
if h.respond_to?(:key?) && h.key?('text') #with respond_to method check if it's hash
   puts h['text'] 
end
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?