# Check command line argument in Ruby code is present

Tags: ruby

I want to execute Ruby code if command line argument is present:

```
ruby sanity_checks.rb --trx-request -e staging_psp -g all
```

Ruby code:

```
def execute
    command_options = CommandOptionsProcessor.parse_command_options
    request_type    = command_options[:env]
    tested_env      = command_options[:trx-request]   // check here if flag is present
    tested_gateways = gateway_names(env: tested_env, gateway_list: command_options[:gateways])
    error_logs      = []

   if(request_type.nil?)
    tested_gateways.each do |gateway|
      ........
    end
   end

    raise error_logs.join("\n") if error_logs.any?
  end
```

How I can get the argument `--trx-request` and check is it present?

EDIT:

Command parser:

```
class CommandOptionsProcessor

  def self.parse_command_options
    command_options = {}
    opt_parser = OptionParser.new do |opt|
      opt.banner = 'Usage: ruby sanity_checks.rb [OPTIONS]'
      opt.separator  "Options:"

      opt.on('-e TEST_ENV', '--env TEST_ENV','Set tested environment (underscored).') do |setting|
        command_options[:env] = setting
      end

      opt.on('-g X,Y,Z', '--gateways X,Y,Z', Array, 'Set tested gateways (comma separated, no spaces).') do |setting|
        command_options[:gateways] = setting
      end
    end

    opt_parser.parse!(ARGV)

    command_options
  end
end
```

Can you advice?

Comment: `command_options[:trx_request]` (note underscore) should work.

Comment: What is `CommandOptionsProcessor`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a specific key is present in a hash or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528506/how-to-check-if-a-specific-key-is-present-in-a-hash-or-not)

Comment: @PeterPenzov please post your `OptionParser` (`CommandOptionsProcessor`) it is difficult to help without the full context

Comment: @engineersmnky Post is updated.

Comment: @engineersmnky Can you paste official answer so that I can vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a boolean switch option to your `OptionParser` like so

```
opt.on('-t','--[no-]trx-request','Signifies a TRX Request') do |v|
  # note we used an underscore rather than a hyphen to make this symbol 
  # easier to access
  command_options[:trx_request] = v 
end
```

Then in your `execute` method you can access this as

```
command_options[:trx_request]
```

If you need to have a default value you can add one in the `parse_command_options` method by setting it outside the `OptionParser` as `command_options[:trx_request] = false`

Comment: By the way what will happen if argument --trx-request is missing? Can I check it with trx_request.present?

Comment: @PeterPenzov `present?` is a `rails` method, so unless you are using rails no. If the flag is missing using `Hash#[]` will result in `nil` (which is falsey and will work in most cases). If you need an explicit `false` then set that as the default option as mentioned in my answer.